# CSS equal width and height grid boxes in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I am trying to have these boxes in a grid and have it be responsive, maintaining equal height and with with the largest box.

It's working the way I want it to in chrome but of course IE is giving me problems.

View it in Chrome to see how I want it to function (take note on how the boxes in each row adjust to the size of the tallest box)

Then view in IE. I'm using IE11.

I'm sure there are some -ms- tags needed, and I've tried but can get this working correctly in IE.

Any help is much appreciated.

[click here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXwOXj?editors=1100)

```
<div class="aaChartWrap">
  <div class="docWrap">

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title Title Title Title Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title Title Title Title </p>
      <div>Download</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title </p>
      <div>View</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title Title Title</p>
      <div>Download</div>
    </a>

    <a class="docItem" href="#" target="_blank">
      <p>Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</p>
      <div>Download</div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>



.docWrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
.docItem {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 92%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 34px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.docItem .docDrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.docItem:hover, .docItem:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.docItem p {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}

.docItem div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0098c3;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .docItem {
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .docItem {
    padding-bottom: 34px;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I think I was auto-prefixing when I originally wrote my answer and pasted the non-IE11 compliant `CSS`. Here are the updated styles which I verified in an actual IE11 environment.

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[3]
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.b {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.c {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.d {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.e {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.f {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

---

The way I got boxes to go where I wanted in IE11, I had to explicitly place them using `grid-column` and `grid-row`. Since `1` is the default value for these properties, I let that value happen implicitly. Also, no vendor prefixes were needed.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;  
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;  
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.d {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">content</div>
  <div class="b">content goes here content goes here content goes here content goes here content goes here content goes here </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d">content</div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="f">content goes here content goes here content goes here content goes here content goes here </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work for IE11...

Comment: @Leviathan I updated my answer. Please have a look (✅ verified in IE11 environment).